# AFNetworking and CLLocation Manager iOS

Tags: ios, afnetworking, locationmanager

My question is as follows:

When is the location updated when using Location Services? When I called startUpdatingLocation I expected to already have a location returned so I can retrieve latitude and longitude for my  iOS project. These are required parameters for a web service as well but it seems they are returned as nil.

The interface conforms to CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol and I have implemented the methods for it. Anyway here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
      super viewDidLoad];

 // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
if([self.parentViewController  isKindOfClass:[BTMainViewController class]])
{
    BTMainViewController *parent = (BTMainViewController *)self.parentViewController;
    self.sessionKey = parent.session;
    NSLog(@"URL is %@ ", self.sessionKey);
}
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

// also set the URL
self.serviceURL = [apiURL stringByAppendingString:@"/get_employee_closestlocations"];

// set tableview delegate and data source
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;

// adjust for EdgeInset with navigation bar.
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);


// fetch the locations here
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[self fetchLocations];

}
```

didUpdateToLocation implementation

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

 CLLocation *currentLocation = [locationManager location];
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

if(currentLocation != nil)
{
    [self setLongitude:[NSNumber numberWithDouble: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude]];
    [self setLatitude:[NSNumber numberWithDouble: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude]];
}
}
```

Any suggestions would be welcome and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delegate method you are using is deprecated.  You should use `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` and then access the location update from the end of the array -

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation = (CLLocation *)[locations lastObject];
    ...
 }
```

It can take some time to get a location fix, particularly as you have specified `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` - iOS may need to start up the GPS receiver if it hasn't been used recently and then the GPS needs to obtain a fix - if the device is inside or has bad GPS reception this can further delay the acquisition of a location.  You can get an idea of the time to obtain a fix by restarting your device, starting the maps application and tapping the location "arrow" and waiting until the blue location circle collapses down to the blue & white marker.

I would suggest that you invoke your `[self fetchLocations];` from the `didUpdateLocations` method

Also, the [Core Location documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/desiredAccuracy) states -

> When requesting high-accuracy location data, the initial event
>   delivered by the location service may not have the accuracy you
>   requested. The location service delivers the initial event as quickly
>   as possible. It then continues to determine the location with the
>   accuracy you requested and delivers additional events, as necessary,
>   when that data is available.

So, there is a risk that when you do access the location, it may not be particularly accurate.  You can look at the `horizontalAccuracy` property of the `CLLocation` and decide whether you want to accept this location or wait for a more accurate location (bearing in mind that it may not arrive if the device is inside or has poor reception)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it. I had to ask, is the stopUpdatingLocation call still required? So far the data is correctly loaded, the web service returns what i need it to. Now my last problem is filling the locations table, but then again I am only testing with a simulator. I do not have a device at hand.

Comment: Once you have a location and no longer need updates, then yes, call `stopUpdatingLocation` - this helps save battery life as iOS can shut down the location hardware if it isn't required.  Also you can simulate a location using the Debug menu in Xcode.

Comment: Paul, tried it already, however seems no locations are returned for my current location. I will try with more accurate coordinates.

Comment: Did you get the prompt saying that the application wants to use your location the first time you ran the app?

Comment: Sorry, did you mean that the web service returns no locations - I misunderstood.  I thought you meant that the CLLocation was still nil

Comment: No, it's just the webservice returning no locations, that is all :)

Answer (score 0):

> You need to do in viewDidLoad like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.


    mapView.delegate = self;
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES; // Enable it when we want to track user's current    location.

}
```

> after doing this the below delegate method will automatically called.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
                 didUpdateUserLocation:
                 (MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    self.mapView.centerCoordinate = userLocation.location.coordinate;
}
```

Comment: The OP didn't mention a `MKMapView`

Comment: ohh! oops it was misunderstood by me.

Comment: No problem, all i want is the location. Its not really a map using application... yet :) On another note, Paul, seems the service does not return any nearby locations close by for the coordinates accepted by iOS Simulator. Will have to test on a device.